# Database design questions, what do you think?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I have the following entities in my system: `COMPANY`, `POSITION`, `APPLICANTS`. There is many to many relationships between `POSITION` and `APPLICANTS`, but the current model does not show that there is many to many relationships between `COMPANY` and `APPLICANTS`.

Does it make sense to you to have a join table `foo` that has the company_id, position_id and applicant_id or i should have a table that joins `COMPANY` and `POSITION` and another that joins `POSITION` and `APPLICANTS`?

Comment: doesn't POSITION reference COMPANY? Because if so you'd need only join table for POSITION and APPLICANTS and get the relationship between APPLICANTS and COMPANY via POSITION.

Comment: What's the relation between COMPANY and POSITION?

Comment: @user306848 it does, but if i want to find how many applicants a company has, i have to do 3 way join

Comment: @TeodorTalov I see, but you should take the answer from duffymo into consideration.

Comment: @TeodorTalov Can't you hide the 3 way join behind a view? Or is it a performance issue (although the right indices might help)?

Comment: I wouldn't design based on imagined performance issues.  See Knuth quote.  Do your best to model the problem as it is and then get some data.  Switch it up when the data tells you that you should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so.  You can get `APPLICANT` for a given `COMPANY` via JOIN with `POSITION`.

I think a relationship between a `COMPANY` and an individual becomes significant when they shift from `APPLICANT` to `EMPLOYEE`.  I would not model it as you propose.

Comment: In addition to this answer, if the FK from your many-to-many table to `Position` is not merely `position_id` but a compound `FOREIGN KEY (position_id, company_id) REFERNCES Position(position_id, company_id)`, then you could join `Applicants` and `Company` tables directly through the many-to-many table - without using `Position`. Compound Primary Keys are not easy to handle but can help avoiding some Joins.